# If a path is nowhere Holder continuous for any rational $\gamma> 1/2$ then it is nowhere Holder continuous for any $\gamma > 1/2$

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, continuity, brownian-motion, holder-spaces

Let $(B_t)_{t \ge 0}$ be a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. Then almost every $\omega$ in the underlying probability space $\Omega$ has this property: For each $\gamma > 1/2,$ the path $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is nowhere Holder-continuous of order $\gamma$.

A function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}^d$ defined on an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ is called Holder-continuous of order $\gamma>0$ at a point $t_0 \in I$, if there exists a finite constant $c$, possibly depending on $t_0$, such that 
$$|f(t)-f(t_0)| \le c|t-t_0|^\gamma$$ for all $t \in I$ lying in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $t_0$. If for a fixed $\gamma>0$ the above condition of Holder continuity is satisfied at no point $t_0 \in I$, then $f$ is said to be nowhere Holder continuous of order $\gamma$.

I am looking at the proof of this theorem from Bauer's Probability Theory.

It says here that it suffices to prove the analogous statement for a fixed (but arbitrary) $\gamma > 1/2.$ For if that has been done then to each such $\gamma$ will be associated an event $\Omega_\gamma \in \mathscr{A}$ with $P(\Omega_\gamma)= 0$ such that for $\omega \in \Omega \setminus \Omega_\gamma$ the path $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is nowhere Holder-continuous of order $\gamma$. The union of the $\Omega_\gamma$ over all $\gamma \in (1/2,+\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is an event $\Omega_0 \in \mathscr{A}$ with $P(\Omega_0)=0$, and every path $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ with $\omega \in \Omega \setminus \Omega_0$ has the claimed property.

Why, is the path nowhere Holder-continuous of any order $\gamma > 1/2$, if it is nowhere Holder-continuous for any rational $\gamma > 1/2$?

Comment: This should be pretty much immediate from the definition, but I'm not sure exactly what definition is being used here.  What's the book's definition of "nowhere Hölder-continuous of order $\gamma$"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have added the definition from the book.

Answer (score 1):

If a function is Hölder-continuous of order $\gamma$ at a point, then it is also Hölder-continuous of order $\gamma'$ for any $\gamma'<\gamma$.  This is immediate because $|t-t_0|^{\gamma'}\geq |t-t_0|^\gamma$ as long as $|t-t_0|\leq 1$, and for Hölder continuity at $t_0$ you only care about what happens when $|t-t_0|$ is sufficiently small.

So, since there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to but greater than $1/2$, failure of Hölder continuity for all rational orders greater than $1/2$ implies failure of Hölder continuity for all orders greater than $1/2$.